# Reposition element in Bing maps MapLayer Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps

How do you reposition an element within a maplayer? I've successfully added a UIElement to my MapLayer, and it works great! Aside from the AddChild method, I can't figure out how to update the position of my UIElement.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Looks like the methods I need are accessible statically through the MapLayer class. Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are within the MapLayer class. You can reposition an element like so.

MapLayer.SetPositionRectangle( UIElement, LocationRect );